# How do you handle the event of a cell being selected in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable that is a 9x9 grid of cells. I would like to handle the event of a cell being selected in a JTable. I would like to change the background color of a cell when it is selected.

I have already tried this code

```
public class JSudokuTable extends JTable {
    public JSudokuTable() {
        super(9, 9);
        setRowHeight(60);
        setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setGridColor(Color.CYAN);
        setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
        setSelectionForeground(Color.WHITE);
        setSelectionBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Color color, 
                    boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                    
                JLabel comp = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, color, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
                
                if (isSelected)
                    comp.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                else
                    comp.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                
                return comp;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This code does not cause the cells (JLabels) to change background color when selected. How do I handle the event of a cell in a JTable being selected?

Comment: Did you debug your renderer? Is the code executed? Does the isSelectred variable contain the value you expect? Post a proper [mre] if you need more help. We can't copy/paste/execute/test the code provided.

Answer (score 2):

```
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Color color, 
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
```

When overriding a method, always make sure to use @Override to make sure you override the method correctly:

```
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Color color, 
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
```

You will get a compile message when your override the method incorrectly. Check the API for the proper parameters.